# convert sql query form to django orm

Tags: django

I Have a models like this :

```
class Person(models.Model):
    person_id=models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    person_name=models.CharField(max_length=100)
    person_family=models.CharField(max_length=100)
    person_father=models.ForeignKey('Person', related_name='child_from_father',null=True)
    person_mother=models.ForeignKey('Person', related_name='child_from_mother',null=True)

def __str__(self):
    return self.person_family

class Car(models.Model):
    car_id=models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    car_name=models.CharField(max_length=100)
    car_owner=models.ForeignKey(Person)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.car_name
```

there is some query that i want the orm form :

```
1: select person_name from Person
2: select * 
   from Person,Car
   where car_owner=person_id
3: select *
   from Person,Car
   group_by(person_name)

4: select *
   from Person,Car
   where name like %x%
   group_by(person_name)
   having car_id >= 2
```

and at last do u know any good refrence for orm 
thx for help

Comment: This should help you get started. Your queries seem pretty straight forward Check it out.  https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/topics/db/queries/

Comment: Except that those SQL queries are nonsense: you don't specify any join conditions, so you'll just get a cartesian join which is no use whatsoever.

Comment: select * 
   from Person,Car
   where car_owner=person_id -> this first make cartesian join then select same filed in car_owner=person_id and remove others. this is like natrual join !

Comment: any one can't convert this sql to orm ? I read the documataion but have problem with them

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm assuming the group by is for ordering.  If you really want group_by look at aggregates and annotate in django.  My guess of what you are looking for is:

1: Get the person record - select person_name from Person

```
 person = Person.objects.get(<WHERE clause>).values('person_name')
```

2: select * 
   from Person,Car
   where car_owner=person_id

Get the cars belonging to the person

```
cars = Car.objects.filter(car_owner = person)
```

3: select *
   from Person,Car
   group_by(person_name)

Get list of cars sorted by owner

```
car_list = Car.objects.all().order_by('car_owner__person_name')
```

4: select *
   from Person,Car
   where name like %x%
   group_by(person_name)
   having car_id >= 2

List of cars with search criteria

```
car_list = Car.objects.filter(id__gte = 2, car_name__contains = "<search>").order_by('car_owner__person_name',)
```

Cars and their Owners

```
car_list = Car.objects.all().values('car_name','car_owner__person_name')
```

Comment: look at this : Person.objects.filter(person_id__in=Car.objects.values('car_owner')) this query return the persons that are owner . but i need to cars too . cars+its  owners. i mean join.  how do that ?

Comment: It's really not helpful to know SQL when learning to use django queries as so much is going on under the bonnet of django so thinking in terms of joins and groups_bys just leads to confusion.  I suggest you look at the django tutorial again and pretend you know nothing about SQL.